# Toggle filters and attributes in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When user click ng-click i need to remove filters and title attributes in a link .

Again user click ng-click i need to add filters and title attributes in a link.

HTMl :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">

<p ng-click="toggleFilter()">Toggle Filters</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">
          <a href="#" title="{{x}}">{{ x | limitTo: 2 }} {{x.length < 2 ? '' : '...'}} </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

</div>
```

can anyone help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what your filters are doing, but here is what I would do:

#### index.html

```
<p ng-click="toggleFilter()">Toggle Filters</p>
<li ng-if="filter == true" ng-repeat="name in names">
  <a>...</a>
</li>
<li ng-if="filter == false" ng-repeat="name in names">
  <a>...</a>
</li>
```

#### ctrl.js

```
$scope.toggleFilter = function() {
  ($scope.filter == "true") ? '$scope.filter == "false"' : '$scope.filter == "true"'
}
```

Here you have one set of list items which are displayed when $scope.filter is true and one set of list items which are displayed when $scope.filter is false. You can write your custom logic of which names you want displayed in the `$scope.filter == true` part (which it looks like you have no problem doing) and leave the `$scope.filter == false` part a standard ng-repeat. I think the syntax for the ternary operator is almost correct, but I didn't check it.